# Powershell / Azure Functions - Problem connecting using appid and appsecret - Access denied

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions

I got a powershell Azure Functions using this command:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://awesome.sharepoint.com" -AppId $appid -AppSecret $appsecret
```

I get the appid and secret from the key vault and it works. I do connect but when trying to run commands like

```
Get-PnPSite
```

Result:

```
Get-PnPSite : Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.
```

I've got an app and I've granted permissions in the app:
[image]

Any suggestion??

Extra information: 
Using MFA

Comment: Did you hit the Grant permissions button (not the save)?

Comment: Try to add the permissions in this [link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#sites-permissions) to Microsoft Graph.

Comment: @MartinBrandl yes the admin has granted.. I'm setting up another test tenant now that I got full control over.

Comment: @JoyWang what permission do I need?

Comment: Try `Sites.FullControl.All`, i.e. `Have full control of all site collections`.

Comment: @JoyWang I've put the Site.FullControll.All and got the tenant admin to grant the permission. I also tried to use a URL but he only get 404 after applying all the "permission". Anything else that I'm missing?

Comment: @JoyWang where do I apply Sites.FullControl.All .. in Azure Portal or at https://apps.dev.microsoft.com ?

Comment: If your app is v1, just in the portal.

Comment: @JoyWang I've created a new tentant and applyed all the same settings. now I got [Error] Connect-PnPOnline : Token request failed. ..  I've checked if the token is not null etc. Any idea?